# Decrypt signed data from key and signature

Tags: php, openssl

The following PHP function verifies that the `$data` string was signed using `$key` to create the `$signature`:

```
<?php

    $result = openssl_verify( $data , $signature , $key , OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1 );

?>
```

Is there an equivalent PHP function where I can get the original `$data` string if I have the correct `$signature` and `$key`

Comment: When you sign something, you use for *private* key to generate the signature.  Then anyone can use the *public* key to verify the message.  A signature cannot be "decrypted" into the original data.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I don't want to decrypt the signature. I want to get the data that was encrypted not the signature as I already have it

Comment: You can't do that.  It's impossible.  A signature is just so you can *verify* that the message is from the person you think it it's from.  You cannot get the original message from the signature and the (public) key.

Answer (score 1):

I think OP had a misconception about the signing process that I understand because I had it too.

The short answer is: no, there is no such PHP function, because it is impossible.

The digital signature is not just the original message ($data) encrypted with a Private Key.

It's the original message hashed into a "message digest" and then encrypted using a Private Key.
If you were to decrypt the signature with the matching public key, you would actually obtain the "message digest".

However there is no way to obtain the original message from the "message digest" because the hashing process is one way by design.

Verifying the signature is the process of hashing $data with the same hashing function and comparing it to the "message digest" obtained from decrypting the signature with the Public Key.

I guess that's what php function openssl_verify does.

This page helped me understand:
http://www.youdzone.com/signature.html

Answer (score 0):

`$data` IS the original `$data` string, that's what the openssl_verify call does - verify that `$data` is unchanged, using `$signature` and `$key`

If you're asking if a `$signature` can be used to generate the data, then no - even if you have the private key, you still cannot recreate the data.

Imagine if you have a physical document (like a Will), which is signed, and a signature card.  While the signature card (`$key`)allows you to verify the signature is authentic (`$signature`), the signature cannot be used to recreate the original content of the document (say, for example, if ink is spilled across the top of the document, but not across the signature line) - even if you're the original signer of the document.  It can only be used to authenticate THAT document (Will) was, in fact, signed (legally binding).

Digital signatures are a bit more complicated from a math perspective, and provide some subtly different mechanisms for authentication, but in this case the result is the same - a signature cannot be used to recreate an original document, even if you have the signature card (`$key`), and even if you have the private key.